# Failed to execute due to unhandled exception. TorchScript requires source access to carry out compilation, make sure original .py files are available

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, pyinstaller

I am attempting to create an executable for the iColorIt model. The script is running fine in the command prompt however, when I run `pyinstaller icolorit_ui.py --onefile --windowed`, move the application to my base directory with all of the files and run it I get the following error in a pop up:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "torch_sources.py", line 23, in get_source_lines_and_file
> File "inspect.py", line 979, in getsourcelines
> File "inspect.py", line 798, in findsource
> OSError: could not get source code
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "icolorit_ui.py", line 8, in
> from timm.models import create_model
> File "", line 991, in _find_and_load
> File "", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 671, in load_unlocked
> File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 377, in exec_module
> File "timm_init.py", line 2, in
> File "", line 991, in _find_and_load
> File "", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 671, in load_unlocked
> File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 377, in exec_module
> File "timm\models_init.py", line 1, in
> File "", line 991, in _find_and_load
> File "", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 671, in _load_unlocked
> File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 377, in exec_module
> File "timm\models\byoanet.py", line 16, in
> File "", line 991, in _find_and_load
> File "", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 671, in _load_unlocked
> File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 377, in exec_module
> File "timm\models\byobnet.py", line 36, in
> File "", line 991, in _find_and_load
> File "", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 671, in _load_unlocked
> File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 377, in exec_module
> File "timm\models\helpers.py", line 18, in
> File "", line 991, in _find_and_load
> File "", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 671, in load_unlocked
> File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 377, in exec_module
> File "timm\models\layers_init.py", line 10, in
> File "", line 991, in _find_and_load
> File "", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 671, in _load_unlocked
> File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 377, in exec_module
> File "timm\models\layers\conv_bn_act.py", line 8, in
> File "", line 991, in _find_and_load
> File "", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 671, in _load_unlocked
> File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 377, in exec_module
> File "timm\models\layers\create_norm_act.py", line 16, in
> File "", line 991, in _find_and_load
> File "", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 671, in _load_unlocked
> File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 377, in exec_module
> File "timm\models\layers\norm_act.py", line 7, in
> File "", line 991, in _find_and_load
> File "", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 671, in _load_unlocked
> File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 377, in exec_module
> File "timm\models\layers\create_act.py", line 7, in
> File "", line 991, in _find_and_load
> File "", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 671, in _load_unlocked
> File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 377, in exec_module
> File "timm\models\layers\activations_jit.py", line 19, in
> File "torch\jit_script.py", line 1338, in script
> File "torch\jit\frontend.py", line 262, in get_jit_def
> File "torch_sources.py", line 120, in parse_def
> File "torch_sources.py", line 32, in get_source_lines_and_file
> OSError: Can't get source for <function swish_jit at 0x0000021B69C3CCA0>. TorchScript requires source access in order to carry out compilation, make sure original .py files are available.

I went on the pyinstaller github issues and tried to follow with the solutions posed to people with similar issues. However, the solutions were hard to follow and did not work for me.

How can I resolve this?